# Updating a document with Mongoose based on a condition

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

So I have this Task model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;


const taskSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    state: Number,
    created: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
})

const Task = mongoose.model("Task", taskSchema);
module.exports = Task;
```

And I'm trying to find a way to update its state from an API(served using Express)

```
router.route("/:id").patch((req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body)
  const id = req.params.id
  Task.findOne({ _id: id })
  .then((task)=> {
    if (task.state === 0) {
      Task.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: id, state: 0 })
    } else {
      Task.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: id, state: 1 })
    }
  })
  .then(data => { res.status(200).json(data) })
  .catch(err => res.status(404).json("Error" + err));
});
```

What am I doing wrong here? The document does not change

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to find where the task state is 0 and id is req.params.id is the provided _id try this:

```js
router.route("/:id").patch(async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body)
  const id = req.params.id
  await Task.findOne({
      _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)
    })
    .then((task) => {
      if (task.state === 0) {
        Task.findOneAndUpdate({
          _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id),
          state: 0
        })
      } else {
        Task.findOneAndUpdate({
          _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id),
          state: 1
        })
      }
    })
    .then(data => {
      res.status(200).json(data)
    })
    .catch(err => res.status(404).json("Error" + err));
});
```

This issue might be the object id "_id" not matching as this `req.params.id` variable would return as a string but wrapping it in `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)` would help.

Comment: Unfortunately by testing it it seems that the findOneAndUpdate is not working, it's not writing in the DB. Also, when I try to console.log the data i get an undefined

Comment: Okay i have edited it. noticed it wasn't an asynchronous function

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by doing this:

```
router.route("/:id").patch((req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id
  Task.findOne({
      _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)
    })
    .then((task) => {
      if (task.state === 0) {
        task.state = 1
        task.save()
        res.status(200).json(task)
      } else {
        task.state = 0
        task.save()
        res.status(200).json(task)
      }
    })
});
```